# What do to with database credentials in code

Tags: c++, mysql++

I'm using the [MySQL++ library by Tangentsoft](https://tangentsoft.com/mysqlpp/home) to connect to a MySQL database from a C++ program. You pass database credentials to the connect method of a Connection object to connect to your database. Obviously, this is pretty bad: if someone malicious would disassemble your application binary, your systems are compromised.

Now, a work-around to work securely with a database from C++ would be to just use a HTTP client library and have something like a PHP script interact with your database (with your credentials safely stored in a .ini file somewhere private on your server). The problem with this is that you don't get the niceties a library like MySQL++ offers, such as query streams and C++-to-SQL (and back) type conversion.

So if anyone has suggestions to a novice programmer on how to use a library like MySQL++ securely, I'd appreciate it if you'd share them.

Comment: Use passwordless authentication (mysql_config_editor).

Comment: @user2672165: The configuration of the database server is often (almost always?) not under the control of the application programmer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @user2672165, I actually might get access to these kinds of settings

Answer (score 0):

I use MySQL++ too, and although you must feed connection details to the `Connection` constructor, there's no reason that these need be hardcoded into your binary.

I read them from a `/etc/<productname>.conf` file on disk, then pass the resulting `std::string` objects into the constructor. That way, security of configuration file is down to the system administrator. Ultimately, the credentials must be known to your application *somehow* but you can absolve yourself of almost all responsibility for securing them. Crucially, at no point are credentials for a specific database server embedded within the application itself.

You have to do this anyway, unless you want your application to only ever work with one database server, and with a single, unchanging set of credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, but the problem is that the idea is that I want every instance of the application to connect to one centralized database I administer.

I know that this is usually not the way to design systems, but I want to collect calculations from several application instances in one database. We don't want to constantly be merging several databases into one. But security is a concern for ethical and practical reasons.

Comment: @JoshuaSchroijen: Then you're creating your own problem. Either hardcode credentials into your binary or don't, but if you do then you have to accept the drawbacks of doing so. You'll likely find that there is a _reason_ this is usually not the way to design systems.